# Pass value to javascript function jQuery templates

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-templates

i am using jQuery templates with C# and i have the following code

```
 <input type="button" value="View" class="btn btn-success" onclick="ShowDocument("'" + ${DoURL} + "'");" />
```

i want to pass value into the ShowDocument function but the above syntax does not work.

can someone please let me know what the correct syntax should be?

i have tried combinations such as d.DoURL and just DoURL, but nothing works.

any ideas?

Comment: what is DoURL? where it defined? and can you update the question with ShowDocument function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
onclick="ShowDocument('${DoURL}');"
```